# Is there a debian lenny patch to allow apt-get to work with sftp?

Tags: security, debian, sftp, apt

I would like to write things like this in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb sftp://someuser@some.server.org/path other stuff
```

When I try this, `apt-get` complains that there is no `sftp` method for `apt`:

```
# apt-get update
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/sftp could not be found.
```

Has anyone written a patch to add the `sftp` method for `apt`?  All I could find in Google was [this spec](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/apt-sftp-support) for Ubuntu.

Thanks for your help.

**edit**: I forgot to mention that I currently use the `ssh` method, and it works fine.  The reason why I'm looking for an `sftp` method is that I want to setup the repository in a chrooted environment on the server, for more security.  I find it difficult to setup and maintain a chrooted environment usable with `ssh` (because you need binaries and their dependencies inside the chrooted environment, and you need to maintain those in case they need security updates), as opposed to a chrooted environment for `sftp` (simply using the appropriate `sshd_config` options).

Answer (score 1):

This line will need to be in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb ssh://user@packages.example.com /path/to/packages/on_the_server/
```

You'll probably want to setup auto key login and things of that nature. You'll also need to mirror the packages down to a server you control in order to install them this way. Because you'll need an account on the server.

Comment: Oops, reading your answer, I realize that I probably wasn't clear enough in my question.  I'll fix this in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you want a secure file transfer for keeping the packages themselves safe, in which case I'd suggest using `dpkg-sig`, and a non-encrpyted transport such as a chroot'd http server of your preference.

Or using `apt-transport-https` if you want a secure authentication to a SSL enabled web server, which you can configure to run in a chroot'd environment, with or without user authentication (e.g. .htaccess for simple Apache access control).

Since I'm not familiar with your Use Case for an authenticated secure apt server, I may be missing some aspect of your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am trying to protect private packages stored in the repository (this is why I do not use http), and also trying to protect my server from further intrusion, if a hacker gains access to the repository (this is why I would like a chroot'd environment).  apt-transport-https sounds good, but I read that there is no way to configure it to check the server certificate, and from what I read authentication is a problem (you need the password in sources.list).  I may be wrong on this, and if I am, then https is the way to go.